# How to wait for promise in synchronous nodejs function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise, async-await

I create a decrypted file containing my users credentials, using an async method:

```
  initUsers(){

    // decrypt users file
    var fs = require('fs');
    var unzipper = require('unzipper');

    unzipper.Open.file('encrypted.zip')
            .then((d) => {
                return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                    d.files[0].stream('secret_password')
                        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('testusers.json'))
                        .on('finish',() => { 
                            resolve('testusers.json'); 
                        });
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                 this.users = require('./testusers');

            });

  },
```

I call that function from a sync method. And then I need to wait for it to complete before the sync method continues.

```
doSomething(){
    if(!this.users){
        this.initUsers();
    }
    console.log('the users password is: ' + this.users.sample.pword);
}
```

The `console.log` executes before `this.initUsers();` finishes. How can I make it wait instead?

Comment: return the promise and `this.initUsers().then...`?

Comment: You can't "synchronously wait for a promise".  Return a promise and the caller uses `.then()` on the promise to know when it's done.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. Instead of waiting for a promise, can I jut get rid of the promise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571213/how-to-re-write-anync-function-to-be-synchronous

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do

```
doSomething(){
    if(!this.users){
        this.initUsers().then(function(){
            console.log('the users password is: ' + this.users.sample.pword);
        });
    }

}
```

you can't wait synchronously for a asynchronous function, you can also try async/await

```
async function doSomething(){
    if(!this.users){
        await this.initUsers()
        console.log('the users password is: ' + this.users.sample.pword);
    }

}
```